# React Redux Reducers and Immutable Updates

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

In a previous scenario to Update Profile values, i created a new store slice (updatedProfileDetails) and stored a new object there, but i think this isn't the best practice to solve my problem (since i have now two slices profileDetails & updateProfileDetails),

Now I found in redux documentation that we can make immutable update reducers to change data in the same slice without mutate states but in this scenario (set conversation unseen to false) , the API don't send an object as a response but just a success message,

---

SO, I'm trying to passe my conversation ID from Action To reducer to check it and change a single value of this conversation[id]

but i'm unable to make it correctly

My code:
1- Action: where I'm supposed to send id after action success

```
export const updateSeenConversation = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_REQUEST,
    })

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState()

    const config = {
      headers: {
       // headers
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.put(
      `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}/conversation/unseen/${id}`,
      "",
      config
    )
// if success data : {success:true , message:"..."}

    dispatch({
      type: SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS,
      payload: id,  // usually i send data sent from API as dispatch payload,, to check for the exact conversation to update i tried to send id
    })

  } catch (error) { //error...})
  }
}
```

2- my reducer:

```
export const conversationsListReducer = (
  state = { conversations: {} },
  action
) => {
// get conversations works Fine and return a slice conversations{..} that i need to update
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CONVERSATIONS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true }
    case GET_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, conversations: action.payload }
    case GET_CONVERSATIONS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }

// here ERROR
// i cant access the exact value i want "unseen" **NB:CHECK store in IMAGE BELLOW**
    case SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true }
    case SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS:
      return {state.conversations.conversation.map((conversation) => {
        if (conversation._id !== action.payload) {
          return conversation  // return without change if !== myid
        }
        return {
          ...conversation,   // make a copy 
          unseen: false,     // change this value to false/true
        }
      })}
    case SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return { conversations: {} }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

[Redux store Slice Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePvxG.png)

Thank You.

Comment: What is your question or what is, if any, issue you have?

Comment: @DrewReese like i said, my second code (reducer) didn't work
i'm unable to use redux immutable update to this slice of store,, i'm trying to update the value of  conversations.conversation["id sent from action"]['unseen']   `unseen: false` from the same reducer where i created the slice Conversations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I still don't see where in your post you say what isn't working but I'm gathering it is something in the `SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS` reducer case since that's where you focused some comments.

From what I can tell in this reducer case, you are mutating the state invariant from `{ conversations: {} }` to `{ [] }` since mapping returns an array, and isn't a valid object.  When updating state you need to shallow copy the state object ***and*** also any nested state being updated.

```
case SEEN_CONVERSATIONS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state, // <-- shallow copy state
    conversations: {
      ...state.conversations // <-- shallow copy state.conversations
      conversation: state.conversations.conversation.map(  // <-- shallow copy conversation array
        conversation => conversation._id === action.payload
          ? {
            ...conversation, // <-- shallow copy conversation
            unseen: false
          }
          : conversation
      ),
    }
  };
```

Since this reducer case is accessing nested state properties that are possibly undefined, you should also fully declare your state.

```
const initialState = {
  conversations: {
    conversation: [], // <--- now access this deep won't throw error
  },
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

export const conversationsListReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  ...

  case USER_LOGOUT:
    return initialState; // <-- reset to initial state
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for, how to access to the value correctly without mutating the initial one
thank you for your precious help

Comment: @RamziOMARI If you haven't looked into it yet, I ***highly recommend*** adding [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) to your codebase. It (1) cuts out the react-redux cruft/boilerplate (defining action types and creators, reducers, etc..), (2) uses immer.js under the hood to edit draft copies in reducer cases so you can just write logic that updates what you want and the slice handles the immutability, and (3) the reducers it generates can combine into your existing reducer tree without issue. It's written by the same team that created Redux and React-Redux.

Comment: YES, I only discovered it yesterday, I'll definitely use it when i understand how it works. Thanks again

Comment: @RamziOMARI when I integrated it into an existing and fairly mature (3+ years) production app I had fully replaced the old `createStore` with the toolkit's `configureStore` and had a new state slice working all in about 20 minutes; all our existing actions/reducers and unit tests still worked as expected. I was extremely surprised how much easier it was to use than the older React-Redux code. The upgrade is worth it.

Comment: ahaha 20 minutes ! that's awesome, mine still in development phase (2 months) I suppose its more simple now, I appreciate.